# How to get user's own contact card with unifiedMeContactWithKeys(toFetch:)?

Tags: swift, contacts, cncontactstore

It came to my knowledge from the documentation ([here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactstore/unifiedmecontactwithkeys%28tofetch:%29)) and some forum replies that the method unifiedMeContactWithKeys(toFetch:), which fetches the me-card in the phone book by using CNContactStore, was recently made available for iOS as well. The problem is that I regardless get the error saying the method is unavailable for iOS, even though the documentation clearly states it should be available. I have tried several Xcode versions including the latest one but to no avail... Does anyone have any idea what is wrong here?

I desperately looked around old forum posts on this very topic but back then the method was only available for macOS, and there aren't any newer posts after the documentation introduces iOS support, so I felt a bit lost.

Comment: I can replicate the discrepancy, Submit a feedback report via Feedback Assistant. [This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactstore/unifiedmecontactwithkeys(tofetch:)?language=objc) seems to be what Xcode is referencing and not your link.

Comment: Odd. The same documentation in Xcode clearly shows that `unifiedMeContactWithKeys` is only for macOS. Not sure why the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactstore/unifiedmecontactwithkeys%28tofetch:%29 shows it being available for iPadOS and Mac Catalyst. Even stranger is the Swift docs show it available for iOS, visionOS, etc.

Comment: I had asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78010706/cncontactpicker-in-ios about a similar change to another part of the Contact framework docs. (And for the people with an itchy down-vote finger, I'm not suggesting you blindly downvote this question as well).

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone! A really weird discrepancy indeed. For anyone that wants a workaround until/if this method ever becomes available for iOS, use the enumerateContacts(with:usingBlock:) method where you will be able to find your own user contact (esentially the me-card). The downside is that you will need some sort of identifier (e.g. phone number) to extract it from the bunch. Hopefully this helps someone though!